# Django: Remove db rows not present in JSON

Tags: django

As part of the Django project, I would like to mirror API data to local database.

I have managed to update data on unique key, however I am struggling how to remove data from the database NOT anymore present in the API file.

To illustrate this, let's have current API data like so:

```
[
  {
    "foo": "Lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum",
  },
  {
    "foo": "dolor",
    "bar": "newvalue"
  },
  {
    "foo": "adipiscing",
    "bar": "elit"
  }
]
```

and existing database records (foo is a unique key column):

```
| id | foo   | bar          |
-----------------------------
| 1  | Lorem | ipsum        |
| 2  | dolor | sit          |
| 3  | amet  | consectetuer |
```

In this case the lines with id 1 & 2 will be updated (rewriting `sit` to `newvalue` in the process) and a new line for `adipiscing`, `elit` will be inserted.

The question is: Is there any good practice how to determine and remove (in bulk) lines such as id 3 (e.g. unique key `amet`), which are no longer present in the (newly updated) input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the values of your API data `foo` key :

```
api_foo_values = [data["foo"] for data in api_data]
```

So now you want to delete the ones which are no longer in the API data. Just exclude the ones which are still in the API data like so :

```
YourModel.objects.exclude(foo__in=api_foo_values)
```

You'll have all objects for which foo values are no longer in API data. Just call delete on that QuerySet like so :

```
YourModel.objects.exclude(foo__in=api_foo_values).delete()
```

And it'll do what you want.

There is no `bulk_delete` like `bulk_create` or `bulk_update`.

Also if you want you can retrieve the list of `foo` column like so:

```
YourModel.objects.all().values_list("foo", flat=True)
```

This will output `QuerySet("lorem", "dolor", "amet")`. See it as all the current values of `foo` column.